# Afterupdate event to write Date value from Textbox to Textbox with inputmask gives error 80020009 when overwriting

Tags: vba, ms-access

I have an afterupdate event where the value entered in the textbox has to be put into another textbox. Initially this works as long as the second textbox is empty. however when i try to change the data in the first textbox i get error 80020009.

1. Textbox one is called *Valdate*
2. Textbox two is called *actionate*
3. Both have the input mask ##-##-####

When entering the date into *valdate* the afterupdate even triggers and puts the date into *actiondate* minus two days.

This part works.

However when *actiondate* is filled and i change *Valdate* I get the error 80020009.

I found some information on several forums and based on that i tried to set the format of the *valdate* and tried to Dim the *valdate*. I probably did it wrong but both didnt work for me.

the code i use is:

```
Private Sub ValDate_AfterUpdate()

Me.Actiondate = Me.Actiondate & ([ValDate] - 2)

End Sub
```

What i want is that whenever i change the date in textbox 1 that date minus 2 days will be entered or overwrite the textbox 2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use *DateAdd*:

```vb
Private Sub ValDate_AfterUpdate()

    If IsNull(Me!ValDate) Then
        Me!Actiondate = Null
    Else
        Me!Actiondate = DateAdd("d", -2, Me!ValDate)
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: this makes so much sense. Thanks Gustav ! works like a charm.